# Can I create a conditional v-for loop to loop on the same div?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I'm curious is there is a way to have a v-for loop with a conditional statement inside of it so I can reduce redundancies in my program. I have a div tag that needs to loop on the `tagfitlers` object if the `tag_filters` object does not exist, otherwise, I need it to loop on the `tag_fitlers` object.

This is a snippet of my current loop:

```
<div v-else class="text-left mt-2 border" v-for="(filter, index) in tagfilters" :key="index">
         <span v-for="(f, i) in filter" :key="i">
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pr-3 pl-3 pt-3">
                  <!-- Multiselect Search with Tagging -->
                  <div>
                     <multiselect @change="onEdit(filter, 'code', f.code)" class="mb-2" v-model="f.code" placeholder="Search & Select Code Options" :custom-label="customCodesLabel" track-by="code" :options="codesArr"></multiselect>
                 </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

I am hoping to do something like this:

```
v-for="tag_filters ? (filter, index) in tag_filters : (filter, index) in tagfilters"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: to try use computed metods do take need array. v-for="(filter, index) in current_filters". computed:{'current_filters':function() {return tag_filters ?tag_filters :  tagfilters}},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Vue.js,

> Using v-if and v-for together is not recommended. See the style guide for further information.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

You could use a computed property to get the correct list.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      tag_filters: {
        filterC: "tag_filter C.",
        filterD: "tag_filter D.",
      },
      tagfilters: {
        filterA: "tagfilter A.",
        filterB: "tagfilter B."
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getTagFilters() {
      if (Object.keys(this.tag_filters).length === 0) {
        return this.tagfilters;
      } else {
        return this.tag_filters;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(filter, key) of getTagFilters" :key="key">
    <span>{{ filter }}</span>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="tag_filters = {}">Remove tag_filter data</button>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), but not sure if it is enough for what you need:

```
get realTagFilters() {
    return this.tagFilters ?? this.tag_filters;
}
```

And you can call it like

```
<div v-for="(filter, index) in realTagFilters">
```

---

Or you can try with the [logical or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), which also seems to work:

```
<div v-for="filter in (tag_filters || tagFilters)" :key="filter.id">
```